# How to implement HashCode.Combine using SymbolEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, .net-7.0, codegen

After updating packages to .net7 in roslyn code generation project, has `error RS1024 Use 'SymbolEqualityComparer' when comparing symbols` for IEqualityComparer implementation of GetHashCode()

```
public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] TypeSymbolMetaType? obj) => System.HashCode.Combine(obj.TypeSymbol);
```

How to fix HashCode.Combine using SymbolEqualityComparer

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is `TypeSymbolMetaType`? Can you show more of your code?

Comment: What the error message suggests would be using `public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] TypeSymbolMetaType? obj) => SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.GetHashCode(obj.TypeSymbol);`, as [per docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.symbolequalitycomparer.gethashcode?view=roslyn-dotnet) with some rationale explained [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/3427#issuecomment-604103434).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `TypeSymbol` is `ISymbol` then you don't need to use `Combine` in this example:

```cs
public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] TypeSymbolMetaType? obj) => SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.GetHashCode(obj.TypeSymbol);
```

In case you want to combine multiple properties the use the result of the `SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.GetHashCode`:

```
public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] TypeSymbolMetaType? obj) => 
        System.HashCode.Combine(
            SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.GetHashCode(obj.TypeSymbol).
            ...);
```

P.S.

In some cases you might need to use `SymbolEqualityComparer.IncludeNullability`.